# ANT pass javax.net.ssl.trustStore to "compilerarg" or Use it as a "sysproperty"

Tags: java, ssl, ant, jvm-arguments, truststore

I'm trying to pass TrustStore certificate to ant compiler as below

NOTE :- for some reasons I can't add env variable and pass it through _JAVA_OPTIONS. I strictly have to pass it through build.xml only.

```
 <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${precompile}"
           includes="build/**"
           debug="true" fork="true" memoryMaximumSize="256m"
           includeantruntime="false">
           <compilerarg line="-J-javax.net.ssl.trustStore='C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_31/jre/bin/trust.jks'" />
```

It throws error as below :-

```
[javac] Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
[javac] Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
[javac] Unrecognized option: -javax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_31/jre/bin/trust.jks
```

I saw [nice example here](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/java/build.xml) but didn't understand how to pass that sys_property variable to ant compiler

```
<sysproperty key="javax.net.ssl.trustStore" value="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_31/jre/bin/trust.jks"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a compiler argument. It is a runtime property. So trying to pass it as a compiler argument by any means is incorrect.

Comment: Hey @EJP , could you please help me to add this trustStore ? what other way I can use ?

Comment: I have helped you. It isn't a compiler argument. Nothing to do with ANT. It is a runtime property. What more do you need exactly?

Comment: Any other way to tell my application that refer trustStore from my given file ?

Comment: Yes, *pass it as a runtime property.*

Comment: I ran my tests as 'ant -Dtest=testfile.xml retest', is there any way (command line params etc) I can pass *'jvmargs'* etc something that tell my JVM to use that trustStore ?

Comment: The compiler doesn't use a truststore. Your question doesn't make sense.